# The result of the patch code flickers in the gif video

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am a not good at English, so I wrote it using Google Translate.
Express the xyz coordinates of the calculated vector as a 3d scatter plot. Save as gif video
In the gif video, the output value of the patch code part is wrong.
In the patch code filled with red color, the bule color edge part Appear and disappear repeatedly. from the gif video part[Appear and disappear repeatedly Gif video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoMem.gif)

The data written is the xyz coordinate value exported from optitrack in 71 rows and 12 columns.
I couldn't upload the data file because I didn't know how to upload the excel file.

```
clear all
close all
clc

data = xlsread('xyztest11.csv');

a = data(:, 1:3);
b = data(:, 7:9);
c = data(:, 4:6);

Vac = c - a;
Vbc = c - b;

L = sqrt(sum(Vac.^2, 2));
Vac_n = Vac ./ sqrt(sum(Vac.^2, 2));

SC = a + (Vac_n .* L) * 5;  % a를 SC 포인트로 이동

up = SC + Vbc;
down = SC - Vbc;

up_R = up + Vac;
down_R = down + Vac;


faces = [1:size(up, 1); size(up, 1)+1:size(up, 1)*2; size(up, 1)*2+1:size(up, 1)*3; size(up, 1)*3+1:size(up, 1)*4]';
figure
mode=2;  % mode 1 : 일시적 표시 / mode =2 : 동영상 표시
if mode==1
  
    hold on;
    scatter3(up(:, 1), up(:, 2), up(:, 3), 'r');
    scatter3(down(:, 1), down(:, 2), down(:, 3), 'g');
    scatter3(up_R(:, 1), up_R(:, 2), up_R(:, 3), 'b');
    scatter3(down_R(:, 1), down_R(:, 2), down_R(:, 3), 'k');
    xlabel('X');
    ylabel('Y');
    zlabel('Z');
    title('3D Scatter Plot');
    patch('Faces', faces, 'Vertices', [down; up; up_R; down_R], 'FaceColor', 'red', 'EdgeColor', 'b', 'LineWidth', 0.5);
    legend('up', 'down', 'up_R', 'down_R');
else
    try 
       delete("testAnimated.gif");
    end
    for i=1:size(up,1)
         cla;
        hold on;
        maker=[a(i,:);c(i,:);b(i,:);];
        line(maker(:,1),maker(:,2),maker(:,3));
        scatter3(maker(:,1),maker(:,2),maker(:,3), 'r','filled');

        scatter3(up(i, 1), up(i, 2), up(i, 3), 'r');
        scatter3(down(i, 1), down(i, 2), down(i, 3), 'g');
        scatter3(up_R(i, 1), up_R(i, 2), up_R(i, 3), 'b');
        scatter3(down_R(i, 1), down_R(i, 2), down_R(i, 3), 'k');
       
        legend('up', 'down', 'up-R', 'down-R');
        xlabel('X');
        ylabel('Y');
        zlabel('Z');
        title('3D Scatter Plot');
        pp=alphaShape([down(i,:); up(i,:); up_R(i,:); down_R(i,:)]);
        
       ` patch('Faces', pp.boundaryFacets, 'Vertices', [down(i,:); up(i,:); up_R(i,:); down_R(i,:)], 'FaceColor', 'red', 'EdgeColor', 'b', 'LineWidth', 0.5);`
        
        xlim([0 2]);
        ylim([-1 1]);
        zlim([-1 1]);
        drawnow;
        exportgraphics(gcf,'testAnimated.gif','Append',true);
        pause(0.01)
    end
end
```